# Blocking postfix requests and access

Tags: debian, postfix, smtp, log-files

I have noticed that I keep getting trash access to my postfix/smtpd in the `/var/log/mail.log` I see many repeats of

```
May  2 11:09:04 mercury postfix/smtpd[25364]: warning: unknown[164.39.218.210]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: Invalid authentication mechanism
May  2 11:09:04 mercury postfix/smtpd[25364]: lost connection after AUTH from unknown[164.39.218.210]
May  2 11:09:04 mercury postfix/smtpd[25364]: disconnect from unknown[164.39.218.210]
May  2 11:09:07 mercury postfix/smtpd[25408]: connect from unknown[185.234.216.121]
May  2 11:09:07 mercury postfix/smtpd[25408]: warning: unknown[185.234.216.121]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: Invalid authentication mechanism
May  2 11:09:07 mercury postfix/smtpd[25408]: lost connection after AUTH from unknown[185.234.216.121]
May  2 11:09:07 mercury postfix/smtpd[25408]: disconnect from unknown[185.234.216.121]
May  2 11:09:09 mercury postfix/smtpd[25364]: connect from ticketmx.kinopark.am[212.34.242.82]
May  2 11:09:09 mercury postfix/smtpd[25408]: connect from unknown[185.234.216.195]
May  2 11:09:10 mercury postfix/smtpd[25408]: warning: unknown[185.234.216.195]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: Invalid authentication mechanism
May  2 11:09:10 mercury postfix/smtpd[25364]: warning: ticketmx.kinopark.am[212.34.242.82]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: Invalid authentication mechanism
May  2 11:09:10 mercury postfix/smtpd[25408]: lost connection after AUTH from unknown[185.234.216.195]
May  2 11:09:10 mercury postfix/smtpd[25408]: disconnect from unknown[185.234.216.195]
May  2 11:09:10 mercury postfix/smtpd[25364]: lost connection after AUTH from ticketmx.kinopark.am[212.34.242.82]
May  2 11:09:10 mercury postfix/smtpd[25364]: disconnect from ticketmx.kinopark.am[212.34.242.82]
May  2 11:09:12 mercury postfix/smtpd[25408]: connect from unknown[185.234.216.114]
```

I thought I will just ban that `ticketmx.kinopark.am` in `/etc/postfix/header_checks` by adding:

```
/^Received: .*\ticketmx.kinopark.am .*$/ REJECT Sorry, too much spam from kinopark.am
```

I restarted postfix, but then I keep on seeing this trash. Any suggestions? Should I be looking at blocking something else?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Your header checks are looking for a match in the headers of an email. However, the connections shown in your log never get as far as submitting an email. They are connecting, trying to authenticate which fails, then disconnecting.

The best thing you can probably do in this situation is use something like fail2ban. This will monitor the log file for authentication failures, then block the source IP addresses via firewall rules when too many failures are seen from the same IP addresses.

Comment: It looks like an attack, all different IPs

Comment: If it's a distributed attack and you're not getting any repeated attempts from the same addresses at all then there's not a huge amount you can do, as you don't know it's not a genuine user until you get the auth failure. It's still useful to have something that can stop repeated auth failures though.

Comment: fail2ban already includes nice jails for Postfix; you only need to enable them.